# How can I produce lines that aligned by words in java swing textArea?

Tags: java, swing, textarea

lines like this:

```
 id    title         price    quantity    sum

 001   c++ primer    20.0     5           100.0
```

I want the two lines look like the above .The first line is the head.

And lines below are information about books. I try to use blanks to achice it,

but it's not that good.can you  help?thank you.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338521/is-there-an-easy-way-to-output-a-column-wise-csv

Comment: sure you do not want to use a table? You may add such features as editing or copying to this component, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) object.

Answer (score 1):

The better choice is to use a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

If you must use a JTextArea, then you need to use a monospaced font.

```
textArea.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10) );
```

or any other font that that has a fixed size for each character.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you have to use a fixed-width-font. But detecting one which works for all characters is not trivial (or impossible?), because, e.g., Asian characters usually are two latin characters wide.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JEditorPane here with "text/html" content type and make an HTML table.