# How can I create table using ASCII in a console?

Tags: java, console

I would like to organize information like this:

[image]

The information is organized with cells, whereas with `System.out.println` the information would be very disorganized.

[image: or this]

Comment: +1. Not a bad question. If someone has a good library for this, please recommend. Otherwise, look at System.out.format

Comment: You could check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193812/how-to-print-a-table-of-arrays/15194265#15194265) for an example

Comment: Your best bets are mainly to use `System.out.printf(...)` and the equivalent `System.out.format(...)`.

Comment: Not an ASCII table, but similar question here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551186/java-lib-to-build-and-print-table-on-console

Comment: table `mysnort` lmao

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use `System.out.format()` or `System.out.printf()` (`printf` internally simply invokes `format` so both methods give same results).

Below you will find example which will align text to left and fill unused places with spaces. Aligning String to left can be achieved with `%-15s`, which means:

- `%` reserve (placeholder)
- `15` "places" for characters
- `s` of String data-type
- `-` and start printing them from left.

If you want to handle *digits* use `d` suffix like `%-4d` to reserve minimum 4 "spaces", number will be printed from left side of that "column".

BTW `printf` doesn't automatically add line separators after printed data, so if we want to move cursor to next line we need to do it ourselves. We can use `\r` or `\n`, or let Formatter generate OS dependent line separator (like for Windows `\r\n`) with `%n` (note: this "placeholder" doesn't require any data *as arguments*, Java will provide correct sequence based on OS).

You can find more info about supported syntax at [documentation of `Formatter` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
String leftAlignFormat = "| %-15s | %-4d |%n";

System.out.format("+-----------------+------+%n");
System.out.format("| Column name     | ID   |%n");
System.out.format("+-----------------+------+%n");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.format(leftAlignFormat, "some data" + i, i * i);
}
System.out.format("+-----------------+------+%n");
```

output

```
+-----------------+------+
| Column name     | ID   |
+-----------------+------+
| some data0      | 0    |
| some data1      | 1    |
| some data2      | 4    |
| some data3      | 9    |
| some data4      | 16   |
+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: ¡¡A perfect answer!!
¡Thank you so much! 
i could do that i wanted =)

Comment: For fixed requirements, this solution is perfect. For more real life use cases, a library is more appropriate. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35961774/363573.

Answer (score 42):

Try this alternative: [asciitable](https://github.com/vdmeer/asciitable).

It offers several implementations of a text table, originally using ASCII and UTF-8 characters for borders.

Here is a sample table:

```
    ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ Table Heading                                                            │
    ├──────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────────┤
    │ first row (col1) │ with some        │ and more         │ even more       │
    │                  │ information      │ information      │                 │
    ├──────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────────┤
    │ second row       │ with some        │ and more         │ even more       │
    │ (col1)           │ information      │ information      │                 │
    │                  │ (col2)           │ (col3)           │                 │
    └──────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

**Find the latest version:** http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.vandermeer/asciitable

**See also:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39806611/363573

Comment: Plus, they have some beautiful table designs [there](https://github.com/vdmeer/asciitable#grids).

Answer (score 21):

My class I created specifically for doing this is completely dynamic:
https://github.com/2xsaiko/crogamp/blob/master/src/com/github/mrebhan/crogamp/cli/TableList.java

You can use it like this:

```
TableList tl = new TableList(3, "ID", "String 1", "String 2").sortBy(0).withUnicode(true);
// from a list
yourListOrWhatever.forEach(element -> tl.addRow(element.getID(), element.getS1(), element.getS2()));
// or manually
tl.addRow("Hi", "I am", "Bob");

tl.print();
```

It will look like this with unicode chars (note: will look better in console since all chars are equally wide):

```
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ Command │ Description                                                             │ Syntax                     │
┢━━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╈━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┪
┃ bye     ┃ Quits the application.                                                  ┃                            ┃
┃ ga      ┃ Adds the specified game.                                                ┃ <id> <description> <path>  ┃
┃ gl      ┃ Lists all currently added games                                         ┃ [pattern]                  ┃
┃ gr      ┃ Rebuilds the files of the currently active game.                        ┃                            ┃
┃ gs      ┃ Selects the specified game.                                             ┃ <id>                       ┃
┃ help    ┃ Lists all available commands.                                           ┃ [pattern]                  ┃
┃ license ┃ Displays licensing info.                                                ┃                            ┃
┃ ma      ┃ Adds a mod to the currently active game.                                ┃ <id> <file>                ┃
┃ md      ┃ Deletes the specified mod and removes all associated files.             ┃ <id>                       ┃
┃ me      ┃ Toggles if the selected mod is active.                                  ┃ <id>                       ┃
┃ ml      ┃ Lists all mods for the currently active game.                           ┃ [pattern]                  ┃
┃ mm      ┃ Moves the specified mod to the specified position in the priority list. ┃ <id> <position>            ┃
┃ top kek ┃ Test command. Do not use, may cause death and/or destruction            ┃                            ┃
┃ ucode   ┃ Toggles advanced unicode. (Enhanced characters)                         ┃ [on|true|yes|off|false|no] ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

And with unicode chars off (omit the .withUnicode(true)):

```
Command | Description                                                             | Syntax                    
--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------
bye     | Quits the application.                                                  |                           
ga      | Adds the specified game.                                                | <id> <description> <path> 
gl      | Lists all currently added games                                         | [pattern]                 
gr      | Rebuilds the files of the currently active game.                        |                           
gs      | Selects the specified game.                                             | <id>                      
help    | Lists all available commands.                                           | [pattern]                 
license | Displays licensing info.                                                |                           
ma      | Adds a mod to the currently active game.                                | <id> <file>               
md      | Deletes the specified mod and removes all associated files.             | <id>                      
me      | Toggles if the selected mod is active.                                  | <id>                      
ml      | Lists all mods for the currently active game.                           | [pattern]                 
mm      | Moves the specified mod to the specified position in the priority list. | <id> <position>           
top kek | Test command. Do not use, may cause death and/or destruction            |                           
ucode   | Toggles advanced unicode. (Enhanced characters)                         | [on|true|yes|off|false|no]
```

Comment: Also have a look here for more unicodes: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/box_drawing/images.htm

Answer (score 5):

use `System.out.printf()`

For example,

```
String s = //Any string
System.out.printf(%10s, s);
```

will print out the contents of String s, taking up exactly 10 characters. So if you want a table, just make sure each cell in the table is printed out to the same length. Also notice that `printf()` doesn't print a new line, so you'll have to print it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [java-ascii-table](https://code.google.com/p/java-ascii-table/). See also [the author's site](http://bethecoder.com/applications/products/asciiTable.action).

Comment: java-ascii-table seems abandonned. See this answer for an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35961774/363573

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way

Example: Print a table with the values of x² - x + 41 for 1 < x < 42

```
public class PrimeEquation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String header = "";
        header += formatDiv("a-----b-------------b----------c\n");
        header += formatRow("|  x  | x² - x + 41 | Is Prime |\n");
        header += formatDiv("d-----e-------------e----------f\n");
        System.out.print(header);

        for (int x = 2; x <= 41; x++)
        {
            int y = primeEquation(x);
            String str1 = String.format("| %3d | %11d | %8b |", x, y, MyPrimes.isPrime(y));
            System.out.println(formatRow(str1));
        }

        System.out.println(formatDiv("g-----h-------------h----------i"));
    }

    public static int primeEquation(int x)
    {
        return (x*x) - x + 41;
    }

    public static String formatRow(String str)
    {
        return str.replace('|', '\u2502');
    }

    public static String formatDiv(String str)
    {
        return str.replace('a', '\u250c')
                .replace('b', '\u252c')
                .replace('c', '\u2510')
                .replace('d', '\u251c')
                .replace('e', '\u253c')
                .replace('f', '\u2524')
                .replace('g', '\u2514')
                .replace('h', '\u2534')
                .replace('i', '\u2518')
                .replace('-', '\u2500');
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Table]

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.format() with correct method 
Code could look something like this i guess

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
 {
       sb.append(String.format(%-10s,rsMetaData.getColumnLabel(i);
 }
```

As of library i dont think there is any that would do the job, however i might be mistaken! will actually do research on it

Also have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 1):

This also works pretty well http://sourceforge.net/projects/texttablefmt/. Apache licensed too.

Comment: texttablefmt doesn't seem to be available on Maven. Here is another library available on Maven: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35961774/363573

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Shell utility class org.springframework.shell.table.TableModel:

```
      TableModel model = new BeanListTableModel<>(portConfigurations, headers);
    TableBuilder tableBuilder = new TableBuilder(model);
    tableBuilder.addFullBorder(BorderStyle.oldschool);
    //TableUtils.applyStyle(tableBuilder);
    return tableBuilder.build().render(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody needs this type of table:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
|  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Here is my solution:

```java
public class TableShape {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width_and_height=5;
        int count=1; 

        for(int i=0;i<width_and_height ; i++) {
            System.out.println("+----+----+----+----+----+");

            for(int j=0;j<width_and_height;j++) {
                System.out.format("| %2d ", count++);

                if(j==width_and_height-1) { // closing | for last column
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            if(i==width_and_height-1) { // closing line for last row
                System.out.print("+----+----+----+----+----+");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fragments of the idea from @David Celi, I create my own solution.

This is my solution.

I hope it help.

Thanks for @David Celi

```
private static class ConsolePanel {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  fullPanel(21, 5, 3, 3,
            "myTitcccle",
            "myBoxxxdy", "myBvvy2", "myBvvy2"
  );
}


public static void simplePanel(
     int scale,
     int margin,
     int upSpace,
     int downSpace,
     String... titleAndOthers) {

  fullPanel(
       21,
       5,
       1,
       1,
       titleAndOthers
  );
}

public static void simplePanelWithSize(
     int scale,
     int margin,
     int upSpace,
     int downSpace,
     String... titleAndOthers) {

  fullPanel(
       scale,
       5,
       1,
       1,
       titleAndOthers
  );
}

public static void fullPanel(
     int scale,
     int margin,
     int upSpace,
     int downSpace,
     String... titleAndOthers) {

  var marginLimitedBySize = Math.min(margin, scale);

  // scale + margin discrepacies eliminated
  if (marginLimitedBySize % 2 != 0) -- marginLimitedBySize;
  if (scale % 2 != 0) ++ scale;

  int fullSize = (scale * 2) - marginLimitedBySize;
  if (fullSize % 2 == 0) ++ fullSize;
  else -- fullSize;

  var internalTextSpace = String.valueOf(fullSize);

  var marginAsString = " ".repeat(marginLimitedBySize);
  var upperSpace = "\n".repeat(upSpace);
  var lowerSpace = "\n".repeat(downSpace);
  var baseline =
       "_".repeat(scale)
          .replace('_', myFont.BASE_LINE.code);

  var divider =
       "_".repeat(scale)
          .replace('_', myFont.BASE_LINE_BOLD.code);

  var upperLineString =
       myFont.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER.code + baseline +
       myFont.MIDDLE_CENTER.code + baseline +
       myFont.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER.code + "\n";

  var middleLineString =
       myFont.MIDDLE_LEFT.code + divider +
       myFont.MIDDLE_CENTER.code + divider +
       myFont.MIDDLE_RIGHT.code + "\n";

  var bottonLineString =
       myFont.LOWER_LEFT_CORNER.code + baseline +
       myFont.MIDDLE_CENTER.code + baseline +
       myFont.LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER.code + "\n";

  var textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  textBuilder
       .append(upperSpace)
       .append(upperLineString)

       .append(myFont.MIDDLE_FACE.code )
       .append("%s%%-%ss".formatted(marginAsString, internalTextSpace))
       .append(myFont.MIDDLE_FACE.code )
       .append("\n" )
       .append(middleLineString)
  ;

  // "-1" Because the first element in the Array was used as title
  for (int i = titleAndOthers.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    textBuilder.append(
         simpleLineStyle(
              "|%s%%-%ss|\n".formatted(marginAsString, internalTextSpace)));

  textBuilder
       .append(bottonLineString)
       .append(lowerSpace);
  System.out.printf(textBuilder.toString(), (Object[]) titleAndOthers);
}

 private enum myFont {

  MIDDLE_CENTER('\u2501'),
  BASE_LINE('\u2500'),
  BASE_LINE_BOLD('\u2501'),
  UPPER_LEFT_CORNER('\u250F'),
  UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u2513'),
  MIDDLE_LEFT('\u2523'),
  MIDDLE_RIGHT('\u252B'),
  MIDDLE_FACE('\u2502'),
  LOWER_LEFT_CORNER('\u2517'),
  LOWER_RIGHT_CORNER('\u251B');

  private final char code;

  myFont(char code) {

    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[TUIAWT](http://www.bmsi.com/tuipeer/) lets you use [AWT](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt) components in a console window. It doesn't look like it supports [List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) or [Table](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Table.html), though, but it may give you a starting point.

Comment: As of this writing, the last update to TUIAWT seems to be in March 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted a solution for this with these features

- Dynamic width of columns
- If width beyond max, then wrap it to next line.

Here is the [simple pure java solution](https://itsallbinary.com/java-printing-to-console-in-table-format-simple-code-with-flexible-width-left-align-header-separator-line/) which you can use as per your need.

Output will look something like this.

```
+----+------------+--------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+
| id | First Name | Last Name                      | Age | Profile                        |
+----+------------+--------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+
| 1  | John       | Johnson                        | 45  | My name is John Johnson. My id |
|    |            |                                |     |  is 1. My age is 45.           |
|    |            |                                |     |                                |
| 2  | Tom        |                                | 35  | My name is Tom. My id is 2. My |
|    |            |                                |     |  age is 35.                    |
|    |            |                                |     |                                |
| 3  | Rose       | Johnson Johnson Johnson Johnso | 22  | My name is Rose Johnson. My id |
|    |            | n Johnson Johnson Johnson John |     |  is 3. My age is 22.           |
|    |            | son Johnson Johnson            |     |                                |
|    |            |                                |     |                                |
| 4  | Jimmy      | Kimmel                         |     | My name is Jimmy Kimmel. My id |
|    |            |                                |     |  is 4. My age is not specified |
|    |            |                                |     | . I am the host of the late ni |
|    |            |                                |     | ght show. I am not fan of Matt |
|    |            |                                |     |  Damon.                        |
|    |            |                                |     |                                |
+----+------------+--------------------------------+-----+--------------------------------+
```