# Aligning numbers in a table

Tags: java, alignment

This is how the table should look like:

[image]

My table produces the right output. Just need to align the values on the horizontal side.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class tesy

{
    public static void main(String[] args)

```
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    int rows=0, cols=0;
    int a, b;

    System.out.print("Enter number of rows from 1-10");


    rows = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter number of columns from 1-10");

    cols = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int c=1; c<=cols; c++){
        System.out.print("    "+c);

    }
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println(    "----------------------");

    for (int d=1; d<=rows;d++){
        System.out.print(""+d);
        System.out.println(); 

    }

    for ( a=1; a<=rows; a++) 
    {

        for ( b=1; b<=cols; b++)
        {


            System.out.print("    "+a*b);
        }
        System.out.println(); 


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You really need to learn about loops, especially [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Also [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15215434/1393766) may interest you.

Comment: Agreed to comments above, you also need to look into http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Yeah i updated my code but still have problem over the horizontal side.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with tables, you absolutely, positively CANNOT rely on simply just spaces and the \t (escape character for tab). These are considered to be unuseful ways because they can change depending on the extra information in the program.

I'd suggest learning how to use printf()

```
System.out.printf();
```

this is what is used in almost any situtaion dealing with tables and alignment-specific information.

[System.out.printf() training](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and most efficient way to do padding (left or right) is to use `String.format()` method.

Left pad 8 spaces:

```
String.format("% 8d", yournumber);
```