# Refresh stock ticks in a table format in Java's System.out

Tags: java, console

I am using Java to write a console program that retrieving stock ticks from a data source and printing to the console in [table format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-java-in-a-console).

However I don't know how to update the value in the table. Once I got a new price for the stock, I want to refresh the value in the console. I don't want to clear my console and print the entire table with a single value update everytime, it looks pretty stupid. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is 'refreshing' old console input even possible?

Comment: I am working in MacOSX, with the command "top" I could have a dashboard showing the current process performance, and this dashboard are keep refreshing every second as I observed. This is what I would like to do in my java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is OS specific, while native programs can perform coordinate based updates within a console Window, this isn't something inherently supported by Java which treats the console as input and output streams.

Theoretically you could write a program to perform such updates and have Java talk to it via JNI, though this would, in my opinion, be overkill.  You'd be far better spending your time writing a Swing or Web based application in which this type of behaviour is far more easily achieved.

Comment: Previously I think writing a swing application is "overkill" because what I want is just a "top" like console app. With your advice it seems what I want to do in console is unachievable. Thanks for telling me this.

Comment: I reckon the Swing code would be easier to write than the table building code - then the refresh is simply a case of updating your model and calling repaint.