# java program read and print to text file using Scanner

Tags: java, file, loops, printwriter

I am trying to read a text file, and then display the output in another file.
I can only read using Scanner.
input.txt

```
3005045 7
3245436 0
7543536 3
8684383 -1
```

output.txt should be like

```
ID    Number of Bags   Total Cost
**    **************   **********
```

customer pays 20.50 per bag if the bag is 4 or less.
and pays 15.50 per bag if the bag greater than 4.
but if it's 0 or negative number this message should appeared "Error : Wrong Number of Bags"
I did this program, but it works only once(reads one line only)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Bags {
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(fileinput);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileoutput);
    double total = 0, line = 0;
    int bags = 0, ID = 0, count = 0;
    pw.println("ID\t\tNumber of Bags\t\t\tTotal Cost");
    for(int i = bags; i >= 0; i++, count++){
        ID = infile.nextInt();
        i = infile.nextInt();
        if (i <= 0){
            pw.println(ID + "\tError: Wrong Number of Bags\t\t\t");
            break;
        }
        else if (i <= 4){
            total = (80.50)*i;
            pw.printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f", ID, i, total);
            break;
        }
        else {
            total = ((80.50)*4)+((75.50)*(i-4));
            pw.printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f", ID, i, total);
            break;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    pw.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What do input.txt's columns represent? I'm also a bit worried about `i >= 0; i++` because it looks like an infinite loop, unless `i` will always be set to <0 somehow later on

Comment: @jpw If OP doesn't use nextLine() anywhere so there is no problem with consuming line separators. Even if each number would be placed in new line series of `nextInt()` would read them without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that **for** loop over there. Also, you want to read line by line. Here is quick fix of your code:

```
public class Bags {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(fileinput);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileoutput);
    double total = 0, line = 0;
    int bags = 0, ID = 0, count = 0;
    pw.println("ID\t\tNumber of Bags\t\t\tTotal Cost");
    while(infile.hasNext()){

        ID = infile.nextInt();
        int i = infile.nextInt();
        if (i <= 0) {
            pw.println(ID + "\n\t\tError: Wrong Number of Bags\t\t\t");

        } else if (i <= 4) {
            total = (80.50) * i;
            pw.printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f", ID, i, total);

        } else {
            total = ((80.50) * 4) + ((75.50) * (i - 4));
            pw.printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t\t%.2f", ID, i, total);

        }
    }
    infile.close();
    pw.close();
}
}
```

Output.txt

```
ID      Number of Bags                  Total Cost
3005045 7                               548.503245436
        Error: Wrong Number of Bags         
7543536 3                               241.508684383
        Error: Wrong Number of Bags
```

Comment: Thank you, but why when i used the for loop it didn't work ??

Comment: I think user @Pshemo  answers your question about how you were using a for loop here and also how to use the new line characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no surprise that loop can iterates only one time. In each case you have `break`.

Also in this case you shouldn't be using `for` loop, and especially not the way you are using it now. Just take a look at it, your loop would end only when this condition `i >= 0` would be false, which means `i` would have to be negative, but even when `i` would become `-1` like last number from your input it would still be incremented at the end of iteration thanks to `i++` so you would end up with `0 >= 0` condition which is true, so loop would try to iterate again)

Instead use

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
```

This way you will make sure that you will read `int` from file only when there will be next one to read. Just use your predefined `bugs` variable instead of `i`.

Another thing is that you are not including line separators in your `printf` formats. Add `%n` at the end of each one of them, and don't use `\t` but specify space you want each number to hold like

```
pw.printf("%d %9d %40.2f%n",...);
```

Comment: if i remove the break an error message shows Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: why you use %9d and %40.2f ??

Comment: `%9d` will make formater print number in format `________3` so it will reserve 9 "spaces" for your number and place it at the end of it. You can use negative value to set align to left so `%-9d` would print your number like `3________` (where `_` represents space). Same about `%40.2f` - it will reserve `40` places for your number. Even better format then from my answer would probably be `pw.printf("%-15d %-31d %.2f%n", ID, bags, total);`. Try to use it.

Comment: Maybe [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15215434/1393766) will make things easier to understand. Also take a look at [Formatter syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `i` to save "number of bags". See the line `i = infile.nextInt();`. Use another variable, then you should be fine. Also, you should keep reading until end of file, so you probably wouldn't be able to write a `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`-style of loop.