# How to print a 2D array with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to write a program that prints a 2d array with random numbers ranging from 100-10000 and prints out the max number in the array,average,and min. The program will ask the user for the number of rows and column and print random numbers in that array.

Here is my code:

```
Random rand = new Random();

int randomnumber = rand.nextInt(9901) + 100;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter row");
int n = console.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter column");
int y = console.nextInt();

int[][] array = new int[n][y];
array[n][y] = randomnumber;

int k;
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k <= array[i].length; k++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what's the prob you're facing?

Comment: When I try to print the array it doesn't print

Comment: yea it prints nothing

Comment: It doesn't print the array

Comment: You need to fill it with random numbers first. Where's your for loop where you fill your array with numbers?

Comment: Why do you think it should work? Which part of your code doesn't work as you planned?

Comment: "array[n][y] = randomnumber;" you don't assign a number to an int array like this. You assign numbers to individual elements of the int array.

Comment: I am getting output now but how would I right allign it since the output isn't being seperated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill the array with random values, you need to generate random values in a loop, and then write them to the array in that loop. So far you are only generating one value (and putting it in an invalid location).

Additionally, since arrays are 0-based, your loops should be `for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++);`, not `<=`.

Here's some code:

```
// don't declare k here
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){

 for(int k=0;k<array[i].length;k++){
      array[i][k]=rand.nextInt(9901)+100;
      System.out.print(array[i][k]);


 }
 System.out.println(); // separate rows
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how would I make this right align. I'm getting the output but it's not being seperated.

Comment: @kylwalfer You need `System.out.printf` with proper format. Here is one of examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-ascii-table-in-java-in-a-console/15215434#15215434