# /t alternative in system output

Tags: java

I have really simple question! 
I want to output some data but all the strings are variables. So my output table gets out of control and some data goes to other side.

```
       Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

    String test, test1, test2;

    test = sc.nextLine();
    test1 = sc.nextLine();
    test2 = sc.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Name\t\t\tCategory\t\t\tStart Time\t\t\t"); 
    System.out.println(test + "\t\t\t"+ test1 + "\t\t\t\t" + test2);
```

For example if strings are "`test test test`"

```
Name            Category            Start Time          
test            ﻿test                ﻿test
```

Everything looks ok. But if strings are

```
TestingThis
Testingthis222
Testingthisagain

Name            Category            Start Time          
TestingThis         ﻿Testingthis222             ﻿Testingthisagain
```

I know problem is /t command. What alternatives I can use for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/flip-tables

Comment: Both of these are very complicated for me, I'am still trying to figure it out but In my example everything is simple. On my actuall work i have to put like 5 lines and 10 rows with times. Is there any simplier way? 

The problem is that sometimes variables differ so everything gets pushed exactly one /t

Comment: Nevermind. I have done it with a for loop from @Pschemo example. Thank you very much.