# How to add spacing to console output

Tags: java, arrays, format, output

Relatively new to java, took a class in highschool and only took one class in college so far, so forgive me if this is a simple question, but I didn't know how to find an answer online as I don't know how to word the question right for a search. Im trying to fix the spacing in the output of my program. The program uses a bunch of arrays to store information on dogs such as their `name`, `breed`, `age`, etc. and print it all out in a specific format.

Here's how the output should look like:
[image: output]

My output is printed out by calling a method `printTitle()` to print out a header above the dog's information, and then using a loop to print out every dog's information. Here's the code for `printTitle()`:

```
void printTitle() {
    System.out.print("Happy Pet Discount Shop\nToday\'s List of Available Pet Dogs For Sale"
            + "\n==============================================================================================="
            + "\nName\tbreed\tage\tin human age\tRegular price\tDisc rate\tOn sale price"
            + "\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Heres the code where I call `printTitle()` and use the loop to print the dog information. Note: `printEndOfList()` prints out some stuff after the loop, there isn't a problem with it, but i'll include it anyway. Heres the code for the loop:

```
dogNames[0].printTitle();

for(int i = 0; i < dogNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("\n" + dogNames[i].getName()
            + "\t" + dogBreeds[i].getBreed()
            + "\t" + dogAges[i].getAge()
            + "\t" + dogAges[i].getAIHY() //get age in human years
            + "\t" + dogRP[i].getRP()     //get regular price of dog
            + "\t" + dogDp[i].get_dPct()  //get discount percentage on price of dog
            + "\t" + dogRP[i].getRP()*(1 - dogDp[i].get_dPct()/100) + "\n"); //final price of the dog
}

dogNames[0].printEndOfList();
```

As an example i'll do 2 dogs, heres what the output looks like when I run it:

```
Happy Pet Discount Shop
Today's List of Available Pet Dogs For Sale
===============================================================================================
Name    breed   age     in human age    Regular price   Disc rate       On sale price
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Balto   Siberian Husky  8       52      1300.0  25.0    975.0


Scoopy  Great Dane      13      77      1100.0  25.0    825.0


======================== End of List ==============================
Request within for price. Any reasonable offer is considered
We accept cash & credit card no American Express
```

So the code works, but how can I get each dogs information to line up under the heading? All the dog names should line up under `Name`, all the dog breed under `breed`, and so on. How do I do this for all dogs? The dogs and their info are being input by the user, so depending on how long or short the names and other info they input are, the spacing looks different. How do I consistently have it line up under the heading?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using System.out.printf

http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/displaying-text-using-printf-method

You would first have to figure out the width of each column, then you can print out each row like this:

```
 System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", dogNames[i].getName(),  dogBreeds[i].getBreed(), dogAges[i].getAge());
```

In this example, each column is 10 spaces.