# Is there a placeholder specifier in Objective-C string?

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting

Is there a placeholder specifier in Objective-C? Something like `%-15s` which says 15 string characters starting from left? I want to print contents in a table format.

```
+-----+------+
| foo | 1    |
+-----+------+
```

I am referring to [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console), but the answer specified is for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on Objective-C [string format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), they comply with the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), which allows you to specify field alignment and length.

This lets you use something like the following to get the results you want:

```
    NSString *rightAligned = @"foo";
    NSString *leftAligned = @"1";

    NSLog(@"| %15@ | %-15@ |", rightAligned, leftAligned);

   // prints "|             foo | 1               |"
```

**EDIT:**

Per rmaddy's comments, if you're using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` you may have to convert your NSStrings to C-strings to get this to work:

```
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"| %15s | %-15s |",
        [rightAligned cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
        [leftAligned cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: The width specifiers do not work with `%@`. I opened a bug about this with Apple years ago. Still not supported. You need to use `%s` and `cStringUsingEncoding:` to convert the `NSString` to a C-string.

Comment: @rmaddy I tested the above code before posting and it works for me. Xcode 10.2.1, macOS 10.14.4.

Comment: I tested it too. Just discovered something weird. Your code works fine using `NSLog`. But if you use `NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"| %15@ | %-15@ |", rightAligned, leftAligned];` instead, it doesn't work. Very strange.

Comment: I just opened a question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942555/a-format-specifier-such-as-15-works-in-nslog-but-not-with-nsstring-stringwit

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could translate [this Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15215434/77567) to C (or Objective-C):

```
puts("+-----------------+------+");
puts("| Column name     | ID   |");
puts("+-----------------+------+");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("| some data%-8d | %-4d |\n", i, i * i);
}
```

Note that in C, we use `\n`, not `%n`, for a newline. The `puts` function automatically appends a newline, so we don't need to use `\n` in the header strings.

C doesn't have an equivalent of Java's universal `toString` method (which allows `"some data" + i` to work in Java), so I have embedded the literal `some data` in the `printf` format string instead, and adjusted the adjacent format specifier accordingly.