# Create a table and put data inside

Tags: java, function, printing, output

How can I create a table for this code?

The table would show the n and the result.

Something that would look like

I know I can print it using System.out.print(.....) but it there a better way to do it?

```
      fib(n)   result
        9        34
        10       55
        11       89
```

```
class fib
{
    static int fib(int n)
    {
        int f[] = new int[n+2]; 
        int i;

    
        f[0] = 0;
        f[1] = 1;

        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
        }

        return f[n];
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int a = 9;
        int b = 10;
        int c = 11;
        System.out.println(fib(a));
        System.out.println(fib(b));
        System.out.println(fib(c));


    }
}
```

Comment: so basically the question is that you want to print stuff to the console and is there a better way than println?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console)

Answer (score 1):

Right now your code only outputs the results of the `fib` method. The `println` method outputs the data you specify as parameter, and then ends the line.

In addition to `println`, the `PrintStream` class has many methods that allow you to do specific things with outputting text. One method you could use is `print`, which does the same as `println` but does not end the line. This means you can do:

```
System.out.print("\t"); // Print a tab character
System.out.print(a); // Print variable a
System.out.print("\t"); // Print another tab character
System.out.println(fib(a)); // Calculate fib(a), print the result, and end the line
```

Another interesting method is `printf`, which allows you to specify a "format String", that then gets populated with the values of the additional parameters passed to the method.

```
System.out.printf("\t%d\t%d%n", a, fib(a)); // Output the variable a and result of fib(a), and end the line
```

[Format Strings are a pretty broad subject](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), but the above example specifies that two tabs should be printed, with a decimal (`%d`) after the first tab and another one (the second `%d`) after the second tab. The next parameter (`a`) replaces the first decimal, the second parameter (the result of `fib(a)`) replaces the second decimal. The `%n` means "end the line".

You can output the header in a similar manner.

Comment: this doesn't handle if the number is "bigger" than a tab character. The duplicate I found have lots of better answers

Comment: Correct, but seeing as the question was obviously a homework question, I opted to give a simpler answer as to not to overwhelm the poster with advanced formatting Strings.

Comment: Well even if it's a homework question I don't like the "I won't research, gimmeh the code" guys :) I typed "java println table" into google and now I know that he is looking for System.out.format. This means for me that he didn't invest any time in this homework