# Particular Format Table in Java

Tags: java

[Table Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH4ID.png)

I have to create a program that sorts all employees by last name and prints them to the screen in a tabular format.

I am having an issue creating a table in the format attached above. Please see what I have and can help out, at this point I don't know how to set it up so the final output looks like the table attached. Thank you.

````
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee[] employees = {
                new Employee("John","Johnson","Manager",20161231),
                new Employee("Tou","Xiong","Software Engineer",20161005),
                new Employee("Michaela", "Michaelson", "District Manager", 20151219),
                new Employee("Jake","Jacobson","Programmer",00000000),
                new Employee("Jackquelyn", "Jackson", "DBA",00000000),
                new Employee("Sally","Webber","Web Developer",20151218)
        };


// get List view of the Employees
        List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(employees);

// display all Employees
        System.out.println("Complete Employee list:");
        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);


// Functions for getting first and last names from an Employee
        Function<Employee, String> byFirstName = Employee::getFirstName;
        Function<Employee, String> byLastName = Employee::getLastName;

// Comparator for comparing Employees by first name then last name
        Comparator<Employee> lastThenFirst =
                Comparator.comparing(byLastName).thenComparing(byFirstName);

// sort employees by last name, then first name
        System.out.printf(
                "%nEmployees in ascending order by last name then first:%n");
        list.stream()
                .sorted(lastThenFirst)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
class Employee
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private String department;
    private double separationDate;

    // constructor
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,
                    String department,double separationDate)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        this.department = department;
        this.separationDate=separationDate;
    }

    // set firstName
    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    // get firstName
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    // set lastName
    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // get lastName
    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    // set department
    public void setDepartment(String department)
    {
        this.department = department;
    }

    // get department
    public String getDepartment()
    {
        return department;
    }

    public void setseparationDate(double separationDate)
    {
        this.separationDate = separationDate;
    }

    // get salary
    public double getseparationDate()
    {
        return separationDate;
    }

    // return Employee's first and last name combined
    public String getName()
    {
        return String.format("%s %s", getFirstName(), getLastName());
    }

    // return a String containing the Employee's information
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%-8s %-8s %s %8.0f",
                getFirstName(), getLastName(), getDepartment(),getseparationDate());
    }
}```
````

Comment: Duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215326/how-can-i-create-table-using-ascii-in-a-console)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of the [String#format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) method and the [System.out.printf()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf) method for formatting your particular Strings to the console window.

First it would be nice if you modify your **Employee** class so that the `separationDate` is of `int` type and not of `double` type. This would of course also include the **Constructor** as well as the **Getter** and **Setter** methods for this class instance variable. Adding a Getter method to your **Employee** class to convert this integer value to a string date format wouldn't be a bad idea either or just use a date string altogether instead of a numerical value for your `separationDate` instance variable. Never the less... your class could be modified to something like this where either or could be acquired:

```
public class Employee {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private String department;
    private int separationDate;

    // constructor
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName,
            String department, int separationDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        this.department = department;
        this.separationDate = separationDate;
    }

    // set firstName
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    // get firstName
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    // set lastName
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Get Employee Full Name
    public String getFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    // get lastName
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    // set department
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    // get department
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setseparationDate(int separationDate) {
        this.separationDate = separationDate;
    }

    // Get Separation Date (As String)
    public String getseparationDate() {
        String dateString = "";
        if (this.separationDate != 0) {
            String date = String.valueOf(this.separationDate);
            dateString = date.substring(0, 4) + "-" + date.substring(4, 6) + "-" + date.substring(6, 8);
        }
        return dateString;
    }

    public int getseparationDateAsInt() {
        return this.separationDate;
    }

    // return Employee's first and last name combined
    public String getName() {
        return String.format("%s %s", getFirstName(), getLastName());
    }

    // return a String containing the Employee's information
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(firstName).append(", ").append(lastName).append(", ")
                .append(department).append(", ").append(separationDate).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Similar to the toString() method except it will return an object instance 
     * as string in a table style format.<br>
     * 
     * @param options (Optional - Boolean - Two Options)<pre>
     * 
     *     addHeader          - If true is supplied then the Object instance string
     *                          id prefixed with an underlined Header String. If 
     *                          null or nothing is supplied then no header is 
     *                          provided.
     * 
     *     addFinalUnderline  - If true is supplied then an underline is added to 
     *                          the Onject instance string. If null or nothing is
     *                          supplied then no underline is provided under the
     *                          table. If this optional parameter is supplied then 
     *                          a boolean value (or null) <u>must</u> be supplied to the
     *                          'addHeader' parameter.</pre>
     * 
     * @return (String) An Object instance String. A toString in table style format.
     */
    public String toTableString(Boolean... options) {
        boolean addHeader = false;
        boolean addFinalUnderline = false;
        if (options.length > 0) {
            if (options.length >= 1 && options[0] != null) {
                addHeader = options[0];
            }
            if (options.length >= 2 && options[1] != null) {
                addFinalUnderline = options[1];
            }
        }
        String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String header = String.format("%-25s|  %-20s|  %-15s", "Name", "Position", "Separation Date");
        String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
        if (addHeader) {
            sb.append(underline).append(ls);
            sb.append(header).append(ls);
            sb.append(underline).append(ls);
        }
        sb.append(String.format("%-25s|  %-20s|  %-15s", getName(),
                getDepartment(), getseparationDate()));
        if (addFinalUnderline) {
            sb.append(ls).append(underline);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Your instances of Employee are held as elements within the Employee Array named `employees` and now you want to sort them. This can be done with the `java.util.Arrays.sort()` method, for example:

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(employees, new java.util.Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee first, Employee second) {
        return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
    }
});
```

Since you have already created the `getName()` method (which is used to compare in the above code) within the **Employee** class the sort would take care of first and last name sorting should last names be the same.

You're already familiar with the String formatting methods so I'm not going to bore you with that anymore. To get the table you want ( or similar to it) then you can do it this way:

```
Employee[] employees = {
    new Employee("John", "Johnson", "Manager", 20161231),
    new Employee("Tou", "Xiong", "Software Engineer", 20161005),
    new Employee("Michaela", "Michaelson", "District Manager", 20151219),
    new Employee("Jake", "Jacobson", "Programmer", 00000000),
    new Employee("John", "Jackson", "Coffee Mole", 20161012),
    new Employee("Jackquelyn", "Jackson", "DBA", 00000000),
    new Employee("Sally", "Webber", "Web Developer", 20151218)
};
    
// Sort the above Object Array (employees) by the employee's first name.
java.util.Arrays.sort(employees, new java.util.Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee first, Employee second) {
        return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
    }
});
    
// Build the Header string
String header = String.format("%-25s|  %-20s|  %-15s", "Name", "Position", "Separation Date");
// Build the Header Underline string
String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
System.out.println(underline);
System.out.println(header);
System.out.println(underline);
// Build the table data strings
for (Employee empl : employees) {
    System.out.printf("%-25s|  %-20s|  %-15s%n", empl.getName(),
            empl.getDepartment(), empl.getseparationDate());
}
System.out.println(underline); // Table underline to indicate End Of Table
```

**The Console Window *should* display:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     |  Position            |  Separation Date
------------------------------------------------------------------
Jackquelyn Jackson       |  DBA                 |                 
Jake Jacobson            |  Programmer          |                 
John Jackson             |  Coffee Mole         |  2016-10-12     
John Johnson             |  Manager             |  2016-12-31     
Michaela Michaelson      |  District Manager    |  2015-12-19     
Sally Webber             |  Web Developer       |  2015-12-18     
Tou Xiong                |  Software Engineer   |  2016-10-05     
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above **Employee** class code, you may have noticed a method added named `toTableString()`. This method was added to the class to assist with displaying Employee object instances in a table format to the console Window (read the method's javadoc). It **could** be used something like this:

```
Employee[] employees = {
    new Employee("John", "Johnson", "Manager", 20161231),
    new Employee("Tou", "Xiong", "Software Engineer", 20161005),
    new Employee("Michaela", "Michaelson", "District Manager", 20151219),
    new Employee("Jake", "Jacobson", "Programmer", 00000000),
    new Employee("John", "Jackson", "Coffee Mole", 20161012),
    new Employee("Jackquelyn", "Jackson", "DBA", 00000000),
    new Employee("Sally", "Webber", "Web Developer", 20151218)
};
    
// Sort the above Object Array (employees) by the employee's first name.
java.util.Arrays.sort(employees, new java.util.Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee first, Employee second) {
        return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
    }
});

// Display the table in Console Window.
int cnt = 1;
for (Employee empl : employees) {
    if (cnt == 1) {
        System.out.println(empl.toTableString(true));
    }
    else {
        if ((cnt) == employees.length) {
            System.out.println(empl.toTableString(null, true));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(empl.toTableString());
        }
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

**The Console Window *should* display:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     |  Position            |  Separation Date
------------------------------------------------------------------
Jackquelyn Jackson       |  DBA                 |                 
Jake Jacobson            |  Programmer          |                 
John Jackson             |  Coffee Mole         |  2016-10-12     
John Johnson             |  Manager             |  2016-12-31     
Michaela Michaelson      |  District Manager    |  2015-12-19     
Sally Webber             |  Web Developer       |  2015-12-18     
Tou Xiong                |  Software Engineer   |  2016-10-05     
------------------------------------------------------------------
```