# Changing spacing between values in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeBook
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting program\n\n");
        String[] STUDENT_NAMES = new String[] {"Adams", "Baker", "Campbell", "Dewey", "East"};
        int[][] STUDENT_GRADES = new int[5][3];
        
        loadGradeArray(STUDENT_GRADES);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT_NAMES.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.printf("%s %d %d \n", STUDENT_NAMES[i], STUDENT_GRADES[i][0], STUDENT_GRADES[i][1]);
        }
            
        
    } //end main
    
    public static void loadGradeArray(int[][] STUDENT_GRADES)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row<STUDENT_GRADES.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<STUDENT_GRADES[row].length; col++)
            {
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][0] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][0] = 100;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][0] = 84;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][0] = 80;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][0] = 50;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][1] = 75;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assignment for class has me creating a grade book for five students with two exam grades listed by their name. The finished product gives the user the option of either printing the average grade for a student, or printing the class average for a test

I am having trouble with formatting the spacing between the values in the grade book. I want the numbers to be evenly aligned-right, like this:

```
Adams _______75 75 

Baker _______100 75 

Campbell _____84 75 

Dewey _______80 75 

East _________50 75
```

Ignore the '_'. Not sure how to format that

Comment: Can you show what the expected output should be?

Comment: You can specify the widths. Ex: `System.out.printf("%-15s %10d %10d \n"....`

Comment: Side note: in `loadGradeArray` you hard-code the indexes so there is no need for either `for` loop.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I create table using ASCII in a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15215326)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to print the data

```java
System.out.printf("%-10s %d %d \n", STUDENT_NAMES[i], STUDENT_GRADES[i][0], STUDENT_GRADES[i][1]);
```

Check the full code and output here

```java
public class GradeBook
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting program\n\n");
        String[] STUDENT_NAMES = new String[] {"Adams", "Baker", "Campbell", "Dewey", "East"};
        int[][] STUDENT_GRADES = new int[5][3];

        loadGradeArray(STUDENT_GRADES);

        for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT_NAMES.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %d %d \n", STUDENT_NAMES[i], STUDENT_GRADES[i][0], STUDENT_GRADES[i][1]);
        }


    } //end main

    public static void loadGradeArray(int[][] STUDENT_GRADES)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row<STUDENT_GRADES.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<STUDENT_GRADES[row].length; col++)
            {
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][0] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][0] = 100;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][0] = 84;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][0] = 80;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][0] = 50;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][1] = 75;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```txt
Adams      75 75 
Baker      100 75 
Campbell   84 75 
Dewey      80 75 
East       50 75
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will keep everything in a nice, even, columnar format:

```
String[] STUDENT_NAMES = new String[]{"Adams", "Baker", "Campbell", "Dewey", "East"};
int[][] STUDENT_GRADES = new int[5][3];

loadGradeArray(STUDENT_GRADES);

String header = String.format("%-10s %7s %8s", "Name", "Class-1", "Class-2");
String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
System.out.println(underline);
System.out.println(header);
System.out.println(underline);
    
for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT_NAMES.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s %5d %8d%n", STUDENT_NAMES[i], STUDENT_GRADES[i][0], STUDENT_GRADES[i][1]);
}
```

Out put to Console Window should look something like:

```
---------------------------
Name       Class-1  Class-2
---------------------------
Adams         75       75
Baker        100       75
Campbell      84       75
Dewey         80       75
East          50       75
```